Winter Bash 2016
Just a quick heads up that we'll be participating in Winter Bash again this year - for more details on the upcoming festivities, please see below:

The year is rapidly coming to a close, which means even though we typically hate it, it’s time to have some fun...with hats!  That’s right - it’s time for Winter Bash 2016!!
Overview
Most of you remember previous years’ events, but here is a quick little reminder. Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users have fun by earning “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (very similar to badges). We track everyone’s progress using hats in a leaderboard that looks similar to this:

As always, we’re coming up with new hat designs for this year’s fun!
The Details
The event will run from 19 December 2016 up to and including 08 January 2017. Users will be able to see all the hats they’ve earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event. 
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage. 
The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

If you really don't like hats (or possibly fun) then you can opt out (if I recall correctly at the site or network level), and you won't see any hats as you use the site.

It's started! Let's get some hats.

I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because WinterBash 2016 has started.
